# how do I handle file download prompt in 117 version of chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver-io

'goog:chromeOptions':{'prefs:{'download.default_directory':'***/downloads'}} doesn't seem to  be working with 117.

disabling the incognito mode might work, but I would need it in incognito mode.

Tried enabling the flag download-bubble@2,download-bubble-v2@2, but no luck.

prefs: {
'localState':{'browser.enabled_labs_experiments': ['download-bubble@2', 'download-bubble-v2@2']},

Comment: what exactly do you want? clearly define your problem, what do you mean by handle? what behavior you want to achieve, write it clearly.  There are lots of ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use enabled_labs_experiments.

```
args: [ '--incognito'],
localState: {
    browser: {
        enabled_labs_experiments: ["download-bubble-v2@2", "download-bubble@2"],
    },
},
prefs: {
    download: {
        prompt_for_download: false,
        default_directory: downloadDir,
    },
},
```

}

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/238034785/unable-to-disable-the-download-prompt-for-incognito-window-while-running-automation-in-chrome?hl=

Comment: Unable to disable the download prompt for Incognito window while running automation in chrome 119

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4619